# Non-contiguous subsetting of matrix with RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo, submatrix, rcpparmadillo

Hello and sorry for the probably stupid question. I studied a bit of C++ in my past but in the last years I've only used R. I need to transform some R code for a package I wrote using Rcpp and in particular, I'm using RcppArmadillo.
Now I checked the documentation but I spent the last hours trying to make this work. Let's say I have a matrix A and a vector of indices idx. If I want to extract a submatrix containing only the rows corresponding to the indices contained in idx, in R I'd do:

```
A[idx,]
```

while in Armadillo I'm doing this:

```
A.rows(idx);
```

where A is a `mat` object. However, I get the following error:
`not matching function for call to 'arma::Mat<double>::rows(arma::vec&)'` 
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried with a `arma::uvec`?

Comment: I think I solved, thanks a lot! The problem wasn't the command rows but having idx as `vec` instead of `uvec`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Armadillo API documentation for submatrix in [continuous and non-continuous states](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat).

```cpp
arma::mat X = arma::randu<arma::mat>(10, 10);

arma::uvec indices;
indices << 2 << 3 << 6 << 8;

// Subset
X.rows(indices);
```

For subsetting, please see the lengthy article that goes over such cases: https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/

For even more guidance in translating, I wrote up a guide awhile back on common *R* operations and their equivalent in Armadillo.

https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/common-operations-with-rcpparmadillo/